# Can I place a Material Preview in the lower corner of another window?

Tags: interface

Is it possible for me to have a material preview window here in the space highlighted in the photo?

[image: screenshot showing where the window would be place]

If not, is it possible to put one in the same spot as the UV editor window, and have them interchangeable with a click, like you would have tabs in a browser?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to carve out a corner of a window that way, no.   However, you can quickly toggle between two editors by hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd> and the appropriate 'function' key.

[image: Menu to switch editors showing the function keys]

If you click the icon at the upper left of an area, it opens a menu that allows you to switch to a different editor.  To the right of each editor you see 'Shift Fnn' where 'nn' is some number.  'Fnn' means hit the function key of that number.

So instead of a click <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>F10</kbd> to pick the UV editor.

But what do you mean by "material preview"?  If you mean viewing your object in Material preview mode, that's already in the window above the UV editor in your screenshot.  If you mean the preview in the materials window, simply select the material tab in the outliner

EDIT: From your comment on my question.

"Material Preview" is something visible in the Properties editor's *Material Properties* tab.  The preview panel is closed by default so you have to open the panel by clicking on the arrowhead:

[image: Material preview]

The function key shortcut for the Properties Editor is <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>F17</kbd> but a preview will only show in that Material Preview panel if you have a material selected and that requires that you have an object selected in the 3D viewport.  (You don't in your screenshot.)

You can't limit the view to just the material preview, but you can create a Properties Editor window and size it to expose just that information.

Unfortunately that's as close as you can get to what you'd like.

Mostly we settle for looking at the material preview in the properties editor window that's usually open on the lower right in the default Layout view.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and when I said material preview I meant that kind of preview where it shows your material on a sphere.

Comment: @Maple38 That's the preview in the material's properties.  Go to the property editor, (open on the bottom right in your screenshot) when you have an object selected and click the tab for the material properties.  I'll add a screenshot to the answer.